# Can't get sorted bar plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, xgboost, np.argsort

I am trying to get a bar plot for feature importance in the XGBoost classifier. It should have worked but it didn't. I tried too many times. Can you check the code below and tell me what is wrong with it?

```
feat_import=clf.feature_importances_
feat_names=X.columns
sorted_idx=clf.feature_importances_.argsort()[-20:]
plt.barh(feat_names[sorted_idx], clf.feature_importances_[sorted_idx])
```

[image: bar-graph]

It takes the features that the most important ones. However, it plots them unsorted.

When I use just numbers instead of column names I take the sorted bar graph.

```
plt.barh(range(20),feat_import[sorted_idx])
```

[image: bar-graph 2]

I couldn't figure out the problem here.

Comment: I couldn't add embedded figures instead of links.

Comment: You could sort the dataframe by a column you want using `sort_df = df.sort_values(by=['columnName'], ascending=False)`

Comment: It is a good idea. Thanks.